# how to set pagination in Joomla Search Plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla1.7

```
i have in problem i make a Plugin for search. 
its work good and no problem ahead to search result but 
i dot got pagination in my search result.
```

i dont know how to set pagination in Joomla search plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really go accept some answer, you will get much better results.

Anyhow, when in doubt you should check the Joomla documentation. This is for a component, but it should get you in the right direction.

http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component